# Counting number of elements in angular view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Angular newbie here.
I've this angular view where there will be multiple 'dashboard-rows' and those will have multiple 'dashboard-columns'. I want to assign each 'dashboard-columns' a unique id by using counter. But I am not able to keep the counter that'll persist through all the rows. Any ideas?

```
<div class="dashboard-rows count{{$index}}" ng-style="{'height': row.height}">
    <div class="dashbord-columns" ng-repeat="column in row.columns" id="gadget{{ counter }}">
   </div>
</div>
```

Basically, I want count of all the 'dashbord-columns' across all it's parents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need `data-ng-class="'dashboard-rows count' + {{$index}}"`.

Or even better: `data-ng-class="'dashboard-row dashboard-row-' + {{$index}}"`.

**EDIT:**

```
<div data-ng-class="dashboard-rows count{{$index}}" ng-style="{'height': row.height}">
    <div class="dashbord-columns"
         data-ng-repeat="column in row.columns"
         data-ng-attr-id="gadget-{{$parent.$index * row.columns.length + $index}}"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Basically I want count of all the 'dashbord-columns'. I don't think your solution gives me that.

Comment: Yes, I understood the question in a different way. What do you think about my edit? It assumes that all rows have equal columns count.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since you need a unique id, how about combining `dashboard-row` index and `dashbord-columns` index with a prefix for each

Ex: `dr{{$dashboard_row_index}}dc{{$dashboard_column_index}}`

Comment: yes that will work too but isn't there any way to get the specific count as the id? Just curious.

Comment: to get the count, you have to loop through the object set at some point, and then you could be running the loop twice (one to get the count and other to print), another option would be to get the count at the end and then update the elements using JS/JQuery. Its up to you to decide if its worth the effort

Answer (score 0):

You can create the counter in your scope.

```
$scope.currentCounter = 0;
$scope.nextGadget= function(){
    $scope.currentCounter = $scope.currentCounter + 1;
    return $scope.currentCounter;
}
```

and for the id;

```
id="gadget{{nextGadget()}}"
```

Another option ( which is not really a counter, but is unique) is:

```
id="gadget{{$parent.$index + '' + $index}}"
```

this is not a real counter, but its unique nevertheless.